# How to generate buy button for each product

Tags: php, mysql

The situation:
I have this table which shows products from database in 2 rows.

```
<table style ="position:absolute; left:0px">
    <tbody>
    <?php
    $i = 1;
    $columns = 2;
    $data1 = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `products` WHERE categorie='1' AND nr_redeems='0' ")  or die(mysql_error());
    while($row1 = mysql_fetch_array($data1))
    {
        if($i == 1){ echo '<tr>'; }
        echo "<td>" 
                    . "<div class=''></div>" 
                    . "<div class='p1'>Some data about it.</div>"
                    . "<div class='p2'><b>Price: "
                    . $row1['nr_points']
                    . " points</b></div>" 
                    . "<button><img style='position:relative; top:0px; left:0px; width:396px; height:121px' src='../img/button.gif'></button>"
                    . "</td>";
        $i++;
        if($i == ($columns + 1)) { echo '</tr>'; $i = 1; }
    }
    ?>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

I also have this in database.php as global ( just mention - to see from where are points and username )

```
$username = $_SESSION['username'];
$data = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `users` WHERE username='$username' ")  or die(mysql_error());
 while($row= mysql_fetch_array( $data )) 
 { 
    $user = $row['username']; 
    $nick = $row['nickname']; 
    $email = $row['email']; 
    $points = $row['points']; 
 }
```

What I want to do: In the table will be generated more buttons, for each product. When press button, I want to check if user have enought points to get the thing. If he had enought..
I want to make the purchase by updating the product to make it unavailable for others and add record into purchases. 
I also want to decrease the user's points with the product's price when he " buy " it.

$points - is the number of points the user already have.
So i am thinking about something like:

```
if ($points > $row1['nr_points']) // if user have enought points

do this...

$final_points = $points - $row1['nr_points'];  // to decrease user's points

$sql1 = "UPDATE users SET points='$final_points' WHERE username='$username'";
mysql_query($sql1) // update the new points value


$sql2 = "UPDATE products SET nr_redeems='1' WHERE id='$row1['id']'";
mysql_query($sql2) // make the product unavailable for others

$sql3 = "INSERT INTO purchases (id, username, productid)
VALUES ('the number for AUTO_INCREMENT ??', '$username', '$row1['id']')";

mysql_query($sql3)  // add the record into database
```

Any ideea how to do this... ? I searched some ways to execute code when press button, but I didn't succeed.

**=============================================================================**

Update:
I found some kind of solution

This is the html code from buy page:

```
<form method="POST" action="">
<input type="hidden" value="100" name="price">
<input type="hidden" value="1" name="productid">
<button type="submit" name="buy" ><img style='position:relative; top:0px; left:0px; width:396px; height:121px' src='../img/button.gif' </button>
</form>
```

And this is the php code from another page:

```
 if (isset($_POST['buy'])) // get data from form I guess
{
   $id = $_POST['productid']; // get the product id and price sended by user when pressed on button
   $price = $_POST['price'];  

   $data112 = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `products` WHERE id='$id' ")  or die(mysql_error());
   while($row112= mysql_fetch_array( $data112 )) 
   { 
      $nr_points = $row112['nr_points']; // get the price of product from database
   } 

   if ($nr_points == $price) // I want to check if the price from database is equal with price sended by user
   {
       if ($points < $price) // check if have enought points
       {
           echo "You don't have enought points"; // just testing
       }
        if ($points > $price) // check if have enought points
       {
           echo "You have enought points"; // just testing
       }
   }
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. This question is a bit too vague. I suspect you're looking for a PHP/AJAX solution in the end. There is a lot of work that I see needing to be done beforehand.

Comment: Actually, lot of time require to understand your idea regarding this problem.

Comment: I try to explain more but the basic ideea is: In that table, will be generated more buttons.. 1 button per each product. When user press on a product's button, I want to modify the database related with user and product.

Comment: @Twisty Yes.. I know is pretty much, but this is a dead end for me and this is the last option. Also I didn't found a better question name.

Comment: @DannyHeck how are the buttons generated? By PHP in the loop or later by JavaScript in the browser? What script updates the database and what info needs to be sent to that script to update the database? Do you want to do this via AJAX or with loading of a page? As I mentioned, there is a LOT to be done.

Comment: The buttons are generated with php loop as you can see. I have no knowledge about javascipt and AJAX so that's 1 of problems.Also there will be like 10-20 products which will have to be generated fom database ( each need to have a buy button ) . $sql 1 2 3 have to be executed to save into database when user press on button but I don't know how to link each button with he's product. I might got an ideea but I don't know if I will find a solution to apply.

Comment: I failed... still can't do it

Comment: It seems I already did that. The solution I posted is working.. I don't know how safe it is, but is working.

Comment: If  concerned about them being changed on the client then i would include a salted hash of the details as an extra parameter in the query parameters. Check the hash when they return. If the hash matches then they haven't been changed.

Answer (score 0):

If I get what you want, Since your while loop generates buttons already with

```
"<button><img style='position:relative; top:0px; left:0px; width:396px; height:121px' src='../img/button.gif'></button>"
```

Simply add form tag to each button

```
 <form method="POST" action="">
```

""

So that each button can have its own action

Comment: it is ugly solution, better is have one form tag and check which button sent the form. IMHO. Also you need set attribute type on button because button is not type submit in default.

Answer (score 0):

Stepping back from the PHP for a moment and just looking at what it would look like in HTML, you might have something like this:

**HTML**

```
<div class='userBar'>
  <label>Name:</label><span id='user'>Nick</span>
  <label>Email:</label><span id='email'>nick@example.com</span>
  <label>Points:</label><span id='points'>100</span>
</div>
<h3>Store</h3>
<table style="position:absolute; left:0px">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <div class=''></div>
        <div class='p1'>First Product Description.</div>
        <div class='p2'><b>Price: 20 points</b></div>
        <button id='button-1' class='buyButton' data-price='20'>Buy</button>
      </td>
      <td>
        <div class=''></div>
        <div class='p1'>Second Product Description.</div>
        <div class='p2'><b>Price: 25 points</b></div>
        <button id='button-2' class='buyButton' data-price='25'>Buy</button>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <div class=''></div>
        <div class='p1'>Third Product Description.</div>
        <div class='p2'><b>Price: 15 points</b></div>
        <button id='button-3' class='buyButton' data-price='15'>Buy</button>
      </td>
      <td>
        <div class=''></div>
        <div class='p1'>Fourth Product Description.</div>
        <div class='p2'><b>Price: 25 points</b></div>
        <button id='button-4' class='buyButton' data-price='25'>Buy</button>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

This can all be populated and created via PHP, so it would be based on your SQL Query.

Using jQuery, a framework for JavaScript, we can add some functionality into the page to build a small user interface. This allows us to control how the buttons work and read data from the resulting HTML that PHP has sent to the browser.

The following is an example of code you may want to use.

**jQuery**

```
var points = 0;
$(document).ready(function() {
  points = parseInt($("#points").text());
  $(".buyButton").click(function() {
    var price = parseInt($(this).data("price"));
    if (price > points) {
      alert("You do not have enough points.");
      return false;
    }
    points -= price;
    $("#points").html(points);
    $.post({
      url: '/echo/html/',
      data: {
        html: "Thank you for your purchase. You now have " + points + " Points.",
        user: $("#user").text(),
        points: points
      },
      success: function(response) {
        alert(response);
      }
    });
  });
});
```

Your code in the end will be different and use specific details from your site, like a URL path to a PHP Page that can handle the actions you want. Much like what you had in your original post. There is not really enough info in your post to be able to advise you further on your PHP Code.

Here is a working example: https://jsfiddle.net/36cub58L/

You can see that when you click a Buy button, if you have enough points, data is posted via AJAX to another script that handles the purchase. If you do not have enough, the script lets you know you can't buy it.

So this is just the tip of the iceberg. Notice I do not use any forms, this helps ensure the users does not muck with your script. Now a smart user will forge the `POST` request and buy the product at a lower price. If you want to allow this, as part of the game, cool! But you can also add in code, using things like `$_SESSION` variables and other checks, to ensure the user can't do those sorts of things.

Remember this is just an example of what you could do. I suspect you will have more questions going forward. Break your questions into smaller parts. Address one element at a time if you can. You'll get a better quicker response.